# Specify quality parameter in node pdf-poppler

Tags: node.js, pdf, poppler

I am trying to convert PDF to image.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf-poppler

```
const path = require('path');
const pdf = require('pdf-poppler');

let file = 'C:\\tmp\\convertme.pdf'

let opts = {
    format: 'jpeg',
    out_dir: path.dirname(file),
    out_prefix: path.baseName(file, path.extname(file)),
    page: null
}

pdf.convert(file, opts)
    .then(res => {
        console.log('Successfully converted');
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
    })
```

However the images generated doesn't have good quality. How I can specify the quality parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good question. You can use 'scale' to increase the size of the image, default is 1024.

```
let opts = {
    format: 'jpeg',
    out_dir: path.dirname(file)+'/images',
    out_prefix: 'test_',
    page: null,
    scale: 4096
}
```

Comment: I would like to know how to find the "scale" para config.  I cannot find any info on the pdf-poppler official usage page. Thanks